# Rotating tensors in TensorFlow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, rotation

Given a Tensor with dimension greater than two, for example with shape `(3, 3, 16, 32)` - how can I rotate the 2D-matrices given by the first two dimension by an angle x?

Example:

```
kernel[:,:,0,0]
array([[ 0.14498544,  0.14481193, -0.18206167],
       [ 0.06301615,  0.15354747,  0.176368  ],
       [-0.16842318, -0.12931588,  0.0105814 ]], dtype=float32)

kernel_rot[:,:,0,0]
array([[-0.18206167,  0.176368  ,  0.0105814 ],
       [ 0.14481193,  0.15354747, -0.12931588],
       [ 0.14498544,  0.06301615, -0.16842318]], dtype=float32)
```

I can easily do this in numpy using `rotated = np.rot90(kernel)` (for the special case of 90 degrees, which is easier to handle because we have no padding), however I am unsure if TF can pick this up as part of a complex computational graph. The kernel in my case I actually a Variable, and in the specific application a weights-kernel of a 2D-Conv layer.

Comment: I don't think your example is a vector rotation of the 3D vectors, but a rotation of a 3x3 "image" about its centre? That has some interesting complications if you want non-right-angle rotations, as you will need rules for padding *and* interpolation . . . also I'm not sure if this is called "rotating" a tensor, it is more like an image processing task.

Comment: Yeah, I actually found [image.rotate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/rotate), but I was not able to figure how to apply this to an arbitrary dimension tensor.